# Unity 2d transform missingrefrence exception, hunting for hours

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have this weird error in unity 2d game i am coding, on awake of scene i am getting gameobjects using

btnblue1 = GameObject.Find("btnblue1").GetComponent();

like this, and storing them and then processing them with refrence to variables and hiding or 
unhiding them using

btnblue1.gameObject.SetActive (true); or btnblue1.gameObject.SetActive (false);

when i go to another scene clicking a button and then come back to this scene, some buttons work fine, but on some buttons as soon as i click them it gives me missingrefrenceexception that transform has been destroyed. i looked many questions here and on google almost all says that check if it exists, but my problem is not that, it already exists and should exist cause i am not destroying it manually. pulling my hairs, any help.

Comment: I don't think that GameObject.Find () works if the gameobject is not active in the hierarchy,  if that's what your asking idk

Comment: if i am going to aother scene and then coming back, shouldn't those buttons be active in the scene. they surely are visible.